# Kohana 3.2 validation custom error adds form.field in front of error

Tags: php, kohana-3

```
public function cc($validation, $value, $field)
{
    if(!$value)
    {
       $validation->error($field, 'error abc');
    }
}
```

So, this code display error message like this: `form.message.error abc`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using `check` method and if it fails then calling errors() method. In view I just loop through the errors array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error message key. You should modify the message file and set your error message key and text there.